# How to optimize mysql queries for nested loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

[image: category table structure] [image: product table structure]I have two tables one is category and other is products.Catid is common for both tables.I am in need to use two while loops to display the data in a table. Its working fine but taking more time and throws error if it process for more categories.

```
   <table>
<tr>
<?php
$cat=mysql_query("select * from category");
while($catquery=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat))
{?>
<td><?php echo $catquery['catid'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $catquery['catname']?></td>
<?php 
 $catid=$catquery['catid'];
 }?>
<?php
$product=mysql_query("select * from product where catid=$catid");
 while($productquery=mysql_fetch_assoc($product))
{ 
?>
<td><?php echo $productquery['productname'] ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can't you use a join in the query ?

Comment: If i have used inner join, individual row is creating for each product name. But i need to display all products name in a single row of the respective category id..

Comment: need to see db structure

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from category a left join product b
on a.catid = b.catid
```

Better define the column one by one, easy for get the data into PHP like :

```
select a.catid as category_catid, 
       a.catname as category_name,
       b.productname as product_productname
from category a left join product b
on a.catid = b.catid
```

If you wanna show all product even `catid` has been deleted in category, you can use this (same with `FULL JOIN`) :

```
select a.catid as category_catid, 
       a.catname as category_name,
       b.productname as product_productname
from category a left join product b
on a.catid = b.catid
union
select a.catid as category_catid, 
       a.catname as category_name,
       b.productname as product_productname
from category a right join product b
on a.catid = b.catid
```

This is how you get the data :

```
while($catquery=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat))
{?>
<td><?php echo $catquery['category_catid'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $catquery['category_name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $catquery['product_productname']?></td>
....
```

Comment: Each productname is displaying in individual rows of category.. @Color Dalnet

Comment: Look like you want to print category once time?

Comment: yes.. with my code i can get output but due to nested while loop its taking time for huge data. @ Color Dalnet

Comment: Here the trick, create a `$temp` variable, and compare it with `catid`. If same, do not `echo`. But make sure it sorted by `catid`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. It will list all category details and their respective  product name(catproducts - in following query).

```
<table>

<?php
$cat=mysql_query("select *,(select group_concat(productname) as catproducts from product where product.catid= category.catid) as catproducts from category");
while($catquery=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)) { ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $catquery['catid']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $catquery['catname'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $catquery['catproducts']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php }//end while ?>

</table>
```

So your output will be

```
catid  catname      catproducts

1      stationary   book,pen
2      leather      wallets,bags
```

Comment: can you please update the code briefly with table and while loop.. @pritzzz

Comment: catproducts showing undefined index error. its not working.. @pritzzz

Comment: Check again THIS line --- $catquery['catproducts'];  --- AND --- group_concat(productname) as catproducts --- THIS line make sure spellings are same.

Comment: I have verified. still same error.have you got the output? @ pritzzz

Comment: yes. Can you please add you code. Edit your actual question.

Comment: Or Change Query ( Edit this line to)  --- $cat=mysql_query("select *,(select group_concat(productname) as catproducts from product where product.catid= category.catid) as catproducts from category");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70456/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-pritzzz).